# USB debugging issue

Tags: android

I'm having an issue with my phone,it not get detected in eclipse IDE as I turned on the debugging mode (nothing in LogCat also).But it's working fine with USB file transferring (get detected as USB mass storage device) I have re-installed the drivers, restart the machine/phone but no result.

```
adb shell
```

also reports as no device found

`adb devices`

also not listing any devices

My phone is:- LG GT540
Windows XP SP2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Refer to my answer here. Let me know if it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306322/adb-wont-start/4622159#4622159)

Comment: Didn't work, but when I do netstat it says that it is established

Answer (score 1):

I've got an HTC and I had to download USB drivers from the HTC site before it would work in debugging mode.

It worked fine as a mass storage device without the drivers but showed up as a 'generic' USB device in Windows Device Manager.

Once I'd installed the HTC drivers it showed up as an 'Android USB Device' and debugging works fine for me. Check the LG support site to see if there are any XP USB drivers available or if they mention it as a known problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try connecting the device on a different system and see if it gets detected. If so, it is probably your system configuration problem. If so, make sure you have correct drivers installed.
2. Sometimes there are too many adb.exe or they ger unresponsive, try resetting adb or kill the instance(Task manager or adb kill) and restart it.
3. Try Rebooting your phone as well as your phone.

You might also want to check this [issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2676);

Answer (score 1):

I have the same phone, had the same issue.

Problem was at 'Settings' -> 'SD card & phone storage settings' -> 'Mass storage only'
was enabled.

Disabling that got it working again properly.

I do not have a clue how that happened. I am 100% sure I never enabled that. See if that might be it for you too.