# why adb server is out of date. killing... on command prompt?

Tags: android

I have updated android sdk upto for Android 2.2 api level 8. After that I was trying to install apk through adb shell as "adb install" but it was not installing and displays "adb server is out of date.  killing..." when I did "adb devices" it was not showing devices. why is that. Please let me know.

Thanks,
Vishakha.

Comment: Have you seen this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092542/adb-server-is-out-of-date/26763766#26763766), maybe related with your problem

Answer (score 1):

After adb is killed, did you run 'adb start-server'?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when I tried to launch my first app today.
And I found the solution.
By the way, I was using Windows7. But I think on Linux, the issue may be similar.

1. found the port that adb required is 5037
   D:\Installs\adt\sdk\platform-tools>adb nodaemon server
   cannot bind 'tcp:5037'
2. check which process in on 5037
   D:\Installs\adt\sdk\platform-tools>netstat -ano|findstr "5037"
     TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3908
     TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         127.0.0.1:54530        ESTABLISHED     3908
     TCP    127.0.0.1:54530        127.0.0.1:5037         ESTABLISHED     10728
3. kill the process 3908

Then start your adb. it should work for you now.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem today, turns out I disabled my network drivers because I had WIFI/LAN issues. re-enabling fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

I have heard of a number of things required to fix this, mainly involving ensuring you do not have conflicting adb.exe files linked in your PATH variable.

The issue with mine is that I am using Genymotion and it was not configured to use the SDK previously installed on my machine. How to fix this can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26763766/2525740).

If you are using HTC Sync or another custom backup application that may contain adb.exe, you can try this tool: [ADBFix](http://visualgdb.com/adbfix/)

Once you have made your changes kill the process running port 5037 as specified by [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15847274/2525740). For me the process was AndroidInterface.exe. Then navigate to the platform-tools folder of the SDK and run adb start-server to restart adb.

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstall the SDK-Tools and reinstall. All good!