# ADB not responding. You can wait more, or kill "adb.exe" process manually and click 'Restart'

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, windows-8.1

I am trying to run an app through my Galaxy S5 using android studio and this message keeps popping up. I have tried killing/restarting abd through cmd to no avail. I have restarted my computer, phone, and android studio, none of which have worked. I have looked in

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\platform-tools

and can't find

> adb.exe

so I suspect this may be the issue but can't find a fix for it.

For clarification, I have been testing my app fine until today when this issue arose. I also just recently updated android studio to 0.8.6 which may have contributed to the issue.

Comment: do adb devices and see if device is detected

Comment: do you have usb debugging turned on in your device?

Comment: Yes, I have been testing the app on my phone for a while and haven't had this problem until now. I recently updated to android studio 0.8.6 which seems to be when this problem started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just re-installed Android Studio and it is working now. I have no idea where the problem came from

Answer (score 0):

You have to type (in a shell) "sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb"

Answer (score 0):

A `Build` -> `Make Project` solved the issue for me. My project then ran normally.

[Source](http://simpledeveloper.com/adb-not-responding-android-solution/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

"From the command prompt run the command adb kill-server. This will shutdown ADB and android studio or Eclipse if you were to use that, would show Waiting for ADB as you said.

Once ADB has shutdown down run adb start-server or run adb devices which will automatically start the adb service and show that your android emulator or development devices has successfully connected."

[ADB not responding. You can wait more,or kill "adb.exe" process manually and click 'Restart'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059334/adb-not-responding-you-can-wait-more-or-killabd-exe-process-manually-and-clic)

Answer (score 0):

I Battled with this problem for a couple of days (nearly drove me nuts) and every solution I found failed to help me. Till I tried the answer by @Mike49.

(On Mac)

I uninstalled Android Studio (moved it from Applications to Trash)

Restarted my Mac

Reinstalled Android Studio (moved it back from Trash to Applications)

And everything was back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Following works for me every time: go to File->Invalidate Caches/Restart select Invalidate and Restart

And, You are good to go.