# HAXM Requires Genuine Intel Processor - Android Studio

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio

[image]Any way to solve this error. I tried to connect with real device but showing 'ADB not responding'?

[image]

Comment: Well, getting a computer with an Intel CPU would "solve the error"

Comment: is there no way to solve this?

Comment: Which thing are you trying to solve? The emulator or ADB to a physical device? If it's the emulator, I'm not psychic, you have to show us what chipset you have.

Comment: I tried to use emulator but it is not working. So i am trying to connect physical device now it is showing 'ADB not responding'

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059334/adb-not-responding-you-can-wait-more-or-killabd-exe-process-manually-and-clic

Comment: I am using ubuntu not windows and i tried it already but result is same

Comment: Read the comments? "Worked for me on Ubuntu" besides the solution said nothing about Windows. It says 1) Kill the adb process (via a terminal) or 2) Toggle the ADB Integration in Android Studio

Comment: try to use `arm images` for Emulator. You can find this in `Other Images` tab at the time of emulator creation.

Comment: please explain @Shashanth

Comment: i tried it so many time i kill the adb process and restarted it but still showing same error @cricket_007

Comment: See the image that you posted in your question, there android studio asking select system image, so click on other images and there you can select `armbeabi` images of android.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you then, other than forget and close Android Studio for a second and see what `adb kill-server` followed by `adb devices` tells you in the terminal

Comment: by typing adb devices it is showing **List of devices attached 
ZY2223SK6K device** Means device is attached

Comment: I downloaded other image but the result is same @Shashanth

Comment: Ok, it's better to use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/), if you really want to use emulator

Comment: i had already installed virtualbox and genymotion but when i tried to open genymotion it shows 'cannot execute binary file'

Comment: Genymotion cannot run ARM images, so you are going to have the same problems as HAXM

Comment: so what to do @cricket_007

Comment: ADB clearly is working in the terminal, so Android Studio seems to be having some issues knowing that. I am not sure what the solution would be

Comment: ok thanks for help @cricket_007 I am trying to fix this.

Comment: Maybe it helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/39506074/4693278