# HAXM requires a genuine Intel Processor

Tags: android-studio

I installed Android Studio and I get this warning message when I want to run a virtual Android device.

I am using an Intel i5 processor and I have enabled hardware virtualisation and installed kvm.

[image: Picture with error message]

Answer (score 1):

This is just Android studio messing up, What you can do is install (even though you already might have) the HAXM, download link is here:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager