# Haxm requires genuine Intel processor (for ubuntu os)

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu, haxm

I have enabled virtualization in BIOS and I have installed kvm in my sytem using instructions from https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/03/12/how-to-start-intel-hardware-assisted-virtualization-hypervisor-on-linux-to-speed-up-intel-android-x86-emulator. But still while running Android studio shows "HAXM requires genuine Intel processor". [Also there is no sdk tool for haxm in sdk manager.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3AWg.png)

Comment: Verify that the machine you are running on has an Intel processor. If it's not an Intel processor then you can't use HAXM. An Intel processor is required for HAXM.

Comment: I have a i5 processor bro!!

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39506074/4693278