# Android - Please ensure that adb is correctly located at specific path

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adb

I know this problem has already asked before a lot. I want developing application on Android device and first of all I follow this steps:

- Downloaded SDK & Java
  [image]
  [image]
- Adding this value to System variables:

android : *C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin;D:\ADDT\developer-tools\android-sdk2\android-sdk2\platform-tools*

JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\

Path : *C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenVPN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin*

- In Eclipse: I assigned this SDK path:
  [image]
- Since I want run on real device , I set Actual device on Run
  configuration:

[image]

- When I run program, in Console I got this:

[image]

- I closed Eclipse and run cmd :

[image]

I connected Samsung S5 with Android 5 and I enable USB Debugging in this phone, and my OS is windows 7.
What should I do?

UPDATED:

Here is my SDK Manager:
[image]
[image]

Comment: try to change the port number of adb

Comment: How to do this? @dex

Comment: eclipse --> preference --> Android --> DDMS --> 8600 change it to some 8601

Answer (score 1):

First thing: Add the full adb path (...\platform-tools) to the system variable 'Path'.
Second, for the 'adb out of date' issue, try to follow the answers here:
[adb server is out of date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092542/adb-server-is-out-of-date)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the latest tolls updated from the Android SDK manager?

Comment: I haven't download system-image for this. is it help me?