# adb server is out of date. killing

Tags: android, react-native, adb, android-sdk-tools

I'm creating my first react-native project with this tutorial: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/

When it comes to executing code and running `react-native run-android` I am getting:

```
adb server is out of date.  killing...
* daemon started successfully *
```

And the app on the android device is obviously not working.

I've reinstalled the SDK, tried to  `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`, but nothing seems to work

I'm using Android 4.4 and Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092542/adb-server-is-out-of-date) . maybe helpful to you.

Comment: updating `adb` helped. [This link](http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/328-ubuntu-trusty-android-adb-fastboot-qtadb) worked, official ubuntu `adb` packages were out of date by 0.01. Thanks!

Answer (score 40):

Open Android Studio, and then update all your build tools, install the SDKs that you need for your device and ensure that have you set `ANDROID_HOME` env var to the same dir that you have in Android Studio (commonly in `/home/you/Android/Sdk`), also update react-native-cli node package. Run adb `kill-server` and adb `start-server`.

Probably you will have problems with adb version, just change your bin:

`sudo cp ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb /usr/bin/adb`

`sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/adb`

Comment: Thanks. your work did the trick. Adb in /usr/bin was older than the adb in android sdk folder

Answer (score 14):

In the latest `adb` update the *adb server is out of date.  killing...* message has been replaced with more informative *adb server version (%d) doesn't match this client (%d)*

So this solution is applicable to both.

The root cause of the error is that your system has multiple `adb` binaries of different versions) installed. These `adb` binaries may come from different sources - distributed together with some development tools or even installed from your linux distribution official repository. I would strongly advise against using any of those sources. The official source of the most recent version of `adb` is the `platform-tools` package from the *Android SDK*. The [`adb` tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/adb/info) contains the direct links to the package.

So if you have *Android SDK* already installed - just update the `platform-tools` package to the latest version using *SDK Manager*. If not - download and unpack the contents of `platform-tools.zip` file for your platform to a folder. Add that folder to your `$PATH`. Now kill all running `adb` processes and make sure to find all other copies of `adb` and delete them. In rare cases some software might stop working. In that case you would need either change that application's internal setting telling it where to find the new binary or if the application uses hard-coded `adb` location - just create a symlink to the new location.

That's it. No more server/client version mismatches. Although you might need to repeat the procedure after installing another software which comes prepackaged with its own `adb` copy.

Answer (score 11):

It might be that you installed the `adb` package in addition to the SDK's. In that case, a

```
sudo apt purge adb
```

might solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting this error using ADB (1.0.32) and Genymotion (2.8.2). My solution was change the ADB of the VM, from my local Android SDK's ADB to Genymotion ADB (default).