# Adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (36) when updated to android 7

Tags: react-native, adb

I'm having this problem: `adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (36)`, when running the command `react-native run-android` in an android emulator (Nexus 5). Everything was fine before i updated android version (SDK, build tools , everything) to **7.0**, to run the newest version of **RN 0.32**. Before i had an idle project in **0.25** and was working fine as i said.

I had ganymotion installed, followed the others solutions relationed to genymotion and did not worked. Now i fully removed genymotion and reinstaled everything in **android 7.0**. Still the same problem.

I saw some fixes to install **ADB 1.0.36** in windows. I cant update my abd (which is **version 1.0.32** right now) further on my ubuntu.

What else can i try?

Thanks very much.

Comment: why do you think you can't update?

Comment: I do find how to upate to 1.0.36 in windows, but not in ubuntu. Its keeps saying that its up to date in version 1.0.32. Maybe i dont know how to update it properly or i'm doing bad searches :/

Comment: Do not use ubuntu repository. It's always outdated. Install `platform-tools` package from Android SDK instead

Comment: Yeah i tried that too.. unistalled the adb from ubuntu repository and reinstalled platform-tools from A-SDK, installed both, nothing seems to put it 1.0.36. What am i doing wrong? Thanks for answering too.

Comment: updating `platform-tools` from Android SDK is just the first step

Comment: I added my answer to another *adb version mismatch* question here http://stackoverflow.com/q/36731277/1778421

Comment: face the same issue with device . you got the solution ?

Comment: I've overcome the same issue by this way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40991118/3765109

Answer (score 11):

I saw an answer here somewhere and the solution was to go to Genymotion settings, go to the ADB tab. Select custom Android SDK Tools, then point to your sdk.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i'm not using genymotion, but maybe i'll switch to it now and try because i can't solve the problem with android emulator.

Comment: @PedroCampolina oh i'm sorry. but yeah, if you are unable to use an actual device, you should use genymotion instead of AVD.

Comment: Thanks, had an issue running my android project from Visual Studio with Xamarin and this solved it, many thanks

Comment: Didn't know you can now develop android using Visual Studio. Lol

Comment: You can develop anything with Visual Studio ;-)

Comment: @NargothBond i used to only use it for visual basic and asp.net. i guess they have been going with trend. can't wait for the android nokia phone. :)

Comment: Please do you have a solution for none Genymotion users? I am testing directly via a USB connected device.