# Run React Native app In device

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to develop simple react native app , i am new in this i get following error , can any one help me ?

```
JS server already running.
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat   install
Debug...
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42321Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoDrawee0110Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFbcore0110Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFresco0110Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipeline0110Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineBase0110Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineOkhttp30110Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookReactReactNative0350Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookSoloaderSoloader010Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareOrgWebkitAndroidJscR174650Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE 
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets SKIPPED
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
 Unknown source file : ERROR: asset directory 'C:\Windows\System32\himanitest\and
 roid\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug' does not exist

:app:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.E
>   xecException: Process 'command 'D:\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished wi
>   th non-zero exit value 1

```
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8.394 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
 set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

Comment: check whether you are able to access adb from command prompt

Comment: Why is your project inside System32 folder? may be build is getting failing due to lack of read/write file permission.

Comment: i get this error adb server version doesn't match this client

Comment: When did you get this error?

Comment: when i try to kill and restart adb server

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39383096/adb-server-version-32-doesnt-match-this-client-36-when-updated-to-android-7

Answer (score 2):

I upgraded compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion and it works

I upgraded it from  compileSdkVersion 23
                    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1" to

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
```