# adb server version (31) doesn't match this client (40); killing... * daemon started successfully

Tags: android, react-native, adb

I am working on react native I am beginner and I facing problem to set  the environment for react native. I have followed 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started' and installing on ubuntu but when I run the command 'react-native run-android' I get the errors: 
 Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
[adb]: adb server version (31) doesn't match this client (40); killing...
[adb]: * daemon started successfully

> Task :app:installDebug 
>   Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Nexus_6_API_27(AVD) - 8.1.0' for app:debug
>   Installed on 1 device.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 37s
27 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 26 up-to-date
Running /home/shafi/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
adb server version (31) doesn't match this client (40); killing...
* daemon started successfully
Starting the app on emulator-5554 (/home/shafi/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell am start -n com.namal/com.namal.MainActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.namal/.MainActivity }

Answer (score 1):

Try these 2 commands with sudo

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Then run `react-native run-android` command and see if it's work.

If it is not working, try below commands

```
   adb kill-server
   emulator -avd Nexus_6_API_27 -port 5557
   adb start-server
```

Then run `react-native run-android` command.

Comment: when I tried the above commands still there was problem of adb is out of date then I find a link ('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36731277/adb-server-is-out-of-date-killing')  to change my bin because I was having problem with adb and I used these two following commands and it worked                                                                        1) sudo cp ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb /usr/bin/adb                                           2) sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/adb

Answer (score 1):

I have tried different solution, But below works for me -

1. Under Home folder (eg:- C:\Users\Lenovo) > find and delete .Android folder
2. Goto, C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android > delete platform-tools folder
3. Again install/download from Android SDK Manager (note: you can open android studio -> tool -> SDK Manager select (eg Android 9.0) apply and ok
4. ( reopen android studio then you can see connected device)
5. if you use visor/ total controller :-

   ```
          Open terminal -
                 adb kill-server
                 adb start-server
   ```
6. Check adb devices, It will work and display you all connected devices.

Answer (score 0):

when I tried the above commands still there was problem of adb is out of date then I find a link ('[adb server is out of date. killing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36731277/adb-server-is-out-of-date-killing)') to change my bin because I was having problem with adb and I used these two following commands and it worked

> Blockquote

```
sudo cp ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb /usr/bin/adb 
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/adb
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can check Task Manager to see what adb.exe processes are running. You can right-click on one of these processes to see the location of the adb.exe file, which may show that it's running as part of an program other than the Android SDK / React-Native.

In my case, I found that the Oculus Developer Hub program came with its own version of ADB, and that copying the following files from my Unity platform-tools folder (in your case, you'd want your Android SDK platform-tools folder) into the Oculus Developer Hub folder resolved the issue - you may just want to uninstall the offending software, but copying the files across should ensure that adb versions are compatible. After copying the files, I ran stopped any adb.exe processes running (using Task Manager), and then restarted Unity.

Files:

- adb.exe
- AdbWinApi.dll
- AdbWinUsbApi.dll

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve this issue is that,

1 - download the Android SDK Platform-tools version that contain adb version 41 from [download site](https://androidsdkmanager.azurewebsites.net/Platformtools) 
2 - replace the folder Platform-tools in C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk with the new one.

3 - from your emulator screen "mobile screen" look at the left options,in the bottom there is three dots "..." click on these dots then "setting" then switch off "Use Detected ADB location", then click on the left folder to locate your db.exe manually chose the file you put in C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\db.exe

restart your software .

Thats all, enjoy