# Adb android conflict with Genymotion

Tags: android, adb, genymotion

My problem is that when i run `adb devices` this error message is shown:

> adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
>   error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: Address already in use
>   ADB server didn't ACK
>   * failed to start daemon *
>   error: cannot connect to daemon

i tryed to set the sdk path in genymotion->Settings->adb but it didn't work.

Comment: update your platform-tools perhaps?

Comment: This is the best answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/26763766/4574306
Go through it.

Comment: Did you try to kill the adb server and started it again?

Comment: To update ADB check this link : http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/328-ubuntu-trusty-android-adb-fastboot-qtadb

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Set Genymotion sdk to the same as Android studion sdk.

Comment: To add a little more context to how to do this: Click the Settings Button->Click ADB tab ->Click Use custom Android SDK tools radio button -> navigate to SDK folder used by Android studio -> Restart Genymotion virtual device