# ADB in Android Studio not working

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using the last version of Android Studio and -without any changes or something- it stop working. It not recognize the emulator or any device

This is the log

```
09:24:51 AM error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:5037: Sólo se permite un uso de cada dirección de socket (protocolo/dirección de red/puerto) (10048)
09:24:51 AM could not read ok from ADB Server
09:24:51 AM * failed to start daemon *
09:24:51 AM error: cannot connect to daemon
09:24:51 AM '...android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe,start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try turning it off and on again (no sarcasm)

Comment: Where is that in AS?

Comment: I have the adb.exe in my task manager...

Comment: just google "restart abd"

Comment: I run 
adb kill-server
adb start-server 
in the terminal and nothing...

Comment: Ok, was worth a shot

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26763766/955843

The adb version are not the same