# How can I resolve "adb server is out of date" error

Tags: android, testing, adb

I understand that this question has been asked 1000 times but every answer I can find on Stackoverflow and other websites are all the same: Either (1) The user is using Genymotion, (2) the user is using HTC Sync in Windows.

I am doing neither. I am currently running in OS/X (10.11.6) and am using a Moto X (2nd gen) phone running Android 6.0.

Many times (not every time) when I run "adb logcat", I get

```
adb server is out of date.  killing...
* daemon started successfully *
```

This is a problem because I am trying to run some automated tests using gradlew (since using "adb shell am instrument" doesn't produce the JUnit style report I need) and collect logs... but every time I start "adb logcat", something in gradlew (apparently) tries to startup adb, which then kills *all* running instances of adb.

Has anyone seen this problem *without* using Genymotion/HTCSync/Windows and knows a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: is your SDK up to date?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adb server is out of date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092542/adb-server-is-out-of-date)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The root cause of the `server is out of date` issue is still the same regardless the OS and/or other software used - you have multiple copies of `adb` binary in your system. And the solution is also the same:

- kill all running `adb` processes
- make sure you have the only copy of `adb` (remove the duplicates)
- update it to the latest version
- reconfigure all your software packages to use that copy

Answer (score 0):

Just check that every tool you use is using the same adb version. For example, delete all versions except the latest.

Answer (score 0):

Please check all your environmental paths which ADB has.
Your system may have several ADB.exe files so that mismatches makes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What cause the error is your computer's adb version is inconsistent with your android sdk's adb version!!!

First,if you use windows,open cmd and input `where adb`,

Second,replace it with your android sdk's adb,

Finally,you get it success.

[image: error info]

[image: success after unify the version]