# Unable to use ADB after updating Android Studio to version 3.5

Tags: android, android-studio

Today, I updated Android Studio to version 3.5 and suddenly ADB has stopped working. I tried using `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`, but still I am getting the below error.

```
adb server version (41) doesn't match this client (39); killing...
ADB server didn't ACK
Full server startup log: /tmp/adb.1000.log
Server had pid: 31799
--- adb starting (pid 31799) ---
adb I 08-21 17:58:31 31799 31799 main.cpp:57] Android Debug Bridge 
version 1.0.39
adb I 08-21 17:58:31 31799 31799 main.cpp:57] Version 1:8.1.0+r23-5
adb I 08-21 17:58:31 31799 31799 main.cpp:57] Installed as 
/usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
adb I 08-21 17:58:31 31799 31799 main.cpp:57] 
adb I 08-21 17:58:31 31799 31799 adb_auth_host.cpp:416] 
adb_auth_init...
adb I 08-21 17:58:31 31799 31799 adb_auth_host.cpp:174] read_key_file 
'/home/user/.android/adbkey'...
adb I 08-21 17:58:31 31799 31799 adb_auth_host.cpp:391] 
adb_auth_inotify_init...
adb I 08-21 17:58:31 31799 31799 adb_auth_host.cpp:467] Calling 
send_auth_response
adb server killed by remote request

* failed to start daemon
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43050370/adb-server-version-36-doesnt-match-this-client-39-not-using-genymotion

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed any path in your computer? Sdk path or anything else? Try to change terminal's default path to `/usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools`  and then execute cthis commands  `adb kill-server`  then  `adb start-server`  then `adb devices`.
And try `invalidate caches and restart`.

Answer (score 0):

The adb version at `/usr/lib/adb` and `~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb` are different, which is causing each to kill the other when run. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40991118/5493555) for a fix.