# adb server version (41) doesn't match this client (39)

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb

im using OS ubuntu and im not using GenyMobile. 
[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lsfea.png)

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43050370/adb-server-version-36-doesnt-match-this-client-39-not-using-genymotion)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did my digging for a while as the accepted answer did not work and landed on this solution
*[I am on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS]*

**What is causing it to happen?**
A clash between two different adb in the system. One in **android/sdk/platform-tools** and another in **usr/bin**

**What will we do?**
delete the adb located in usr/bin, then copy from platform-tools and paste in the usr/bin

Steps:

1. open the usr/bin in terminal as:

> sudo nautilus

2. locate and delete adb in usr/bin
3. open sdk/platform-tools, copy paste adb to above usr/bin
4. lastly perform this in terminal:

> sudo apt update && sudo apt install android-sdk

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same problem on ubuntu 20. This seems to be caused by `apt` installing a different version of `adb` than the one that Android Studio or other SDK tools download. I don't remember ever installing `adb` with `apt`. It was probably pulled in as a dependency.

My solution was similar to Kushagra's, but I used bash and had to kill the adb server to finally get rid of the error

```bash
# Print some info to verify what is going on
> lsb_release -sr
20.04

> which adb
/usr/bin/adb

> /usr/bin/adb --version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
Version 1:8.1.0+r23-5ubuntu2

> ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb --version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 33.0.2-8557947

> apt list --installed | grep adb
adb/focal,now 1:8.1.0+r23-5ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,automatic]

##############################################
# OK, quit horsing around and fix the problem

> adb kill-server
> sudo mv /usr/bin/adb /usr/bin/adb-1.0.39
> sudo cp ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb /usr/bin
> adb --version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41

> adb start-server
```

Beware of the capital 'S' in Sdk. That is where my Android Studio chipmunk installed it, but I think older versions were lower cased as `sdk`.

Also keep in mind that this solution overwrites the system version installed by `apt`. That might be unwise, and is likely temporary. If that is a problem, consider copying in the other direction instead : from `/usr/bin` to `~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools`. Links might be wiser than making file copies.