# Connecting Android Device issue on Windows: adb server version (41) doesn't match this client (39); killing

Tags: android, windows, adb, unreal-engine4

So I've been stuck on this issue when running `adb devices`:

> List of devices attached
> adb server version (41) doesn't match this client (39); killing...
> daemon started successfully

While there are plenty of questions/answers on this topic, attempting/understanding the answers hasn't worked for me.

Here is some info:

- Running `adb version` returns

  > Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
  > Version 0.0.1-4500957
  > Installed as C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe

  Which, to my understanding, should show there is currently only one
  version
- I've tried the `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server` with no results
- Using Windows 10
- The Ultimate Goal here is to get Unreal Engine working with my Android device

I'm kinda getting at my wits end here, and was wondering if any of you had any advice? Let me know if there is anymore info I can give to help solve this issue!

Comment: Please at least describe briefly what you have already tried. I won't write an answer just to hear from yo "oh I already tried this all". You should your complete hard disk for `adb.exe`, I am sure you will find more than one version.

Comment: As a slightly time-consuming, but almost-surefire way to fix this, try to uninstall adb and all other related Android software.

Then install Android Studio *in the way instructed, and of the version specified* [in the official docs here](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/SharingAndReleasing/Mobile/Android/Setup/AndroidStudio/).

Answer (score 23):

That's happened to me right now.

An answer is in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58603140/adb-server-version-41-doesnt-match-this-client-39), but to sum up:

Locate and delete adb in usr/bin:

```
which adb
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/adb
```

Open sdk/platform-tools, copy paste adb to above usr/bin. Example:

```
sudo cp ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb /usr/bin
```

Then:

```
sudo apt update
```

Finally, try again:

```
adb devices
```

Comment: in my case, instad of `~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb` is was `~/android_sdk/platform-tools/adb`

Comment: The OP asked for a windows answer not a Mac/Linux answer

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, in Android Studio, ensure that you don't have Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest) installed, alongside the Build Tools

If you do, just untick to uninstall and restart Android Studio. I have found that restarting the machine as well, is needed in some cases