Getting error while run the instant app in android
I have started exploring the instant app in Android. I have set up all the things like adding the dependency, Manifest things, and thinking deploy as an instant app in the run configuration.
Manifest :
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution">

    <dist:module dist:instant="true" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:targetSandboxVersion="2"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyInstantApp"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

I am getting this error.
.

I solved this error following the answer steps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71865193/connecting-android-device-issue-on-windows-adb-server-version-41-doesnt-matc/74268233#74268233
