# Unable to test app on physical device using android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, daemon

[image]I am trying to test the demo app on a physical Android device (Xiaomi redmi note 7 pro) from the android studio but I am getting the errors listed in this image attached.

It says that

adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (41); killing...

- daemon started successfully

Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Unable to open connection to: localhost/127.0.0.1:5037, due to: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.

- daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
- daemon started successfully

"Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Answer (score 0):

- [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43050370/adb-server-version-36-doesnt-match-this-client-39-not-using-genymotion)
- Check if ADB is used by another application like some screen mirror app etc
- Check whether USB debugging is enabled and Install via USB is enabled
- Try disabling MIUI optimizations in developer options and restarting the device