# ADB error while running android app on phone in IntelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea, adb, daemon

When I click "run" on the top right corner to launch my basic "Hello World" application, my device isn't recognized, and if I set the configurations to give a popup to select either an AVD or a connected device, I get the following errors:

```
7:34 PM adb server version (39) doesn't match this client (40); killing...

7:34 PM could not read ok from ADB Server

7:34 PM * failed to start daemon

7:34 PM error: cannot connect to daemon

7:34 PM 'C:\Users\<MyName>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
```

Developer mode and USB debugging is enabled on my phone, and I have the latest Gradle installed. I believe my Path variables are set correctly and the android SDK, Gradle, and JVM paths are all correctly set in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are running 2 different versions of ADB.

Run `adb kill-server` and then `C:\Users\<MyName>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server`

Add `C:\Users\<MyName>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\` to the beginning of your environment path.

Also, there is already a discussion here: [adb server version doesn't match this client](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5092542/8034839)

Answer (score 0):

Try using command line to connect device.Firstly plug in usb cable,then run below commands:

```
adb kill-server
adb devices
```

And check whether usb cable line work normally.

Comment: you could download standalone adb tool from 
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools#downloads