# ADB doesn't see the device (LD PLayer emulator)

Tags: android, adb, emulation

I'm writing automation for the LD Player emulator. I need to work with a large number of emulators (about 400). But not at the same time.

I've encountered a problem. After successfully processing 16 emulators, adb stopped seeing the devices. I tried restarting it, but that didn't help.

I'm using android studio. I think the problem may be in the line

```
$ADB_LOCAL_TRANSPORT_MAX_PORT max emulator scan port (default 5585, 16 emus)
```

But I didn't find where to change this.

Actually here is my problem. The server is running, there are no devices.
In the emulator settings, root rights and adb are enabled. Windows OS.
In the emulator Android 7.1, Samsung (but most likely the phone model is not important)

```
C:\Users\MoT>adb devices
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
List of devices attached
```

Command

C:\Users\MoT>adb devices
mast return somethink like that

C:\Users\MoT>adb devices
adb server version (31) doesn't match this client (41); killing...

- daemon started successfully
  List of devices attached
  emulator-5554   device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't necessarily call "uninstalling Android Studio" a "solution". See [`transport_local.cpp`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:packages/modules/adb/client/transport_local.cpp;l=56); one can set environmental variable `ADB_LOCAL_TRANSPORT_MAX_PORT` to override the scan-range limit. The problem is, that you're already running the wrong version of ADB server: [adb server version doesn't match this client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092542/adb-server-version-doesnt-match-this-client), which usually can be solved with `adb kill-server`.

Comment: Right. The LD player has its own adb and they conflicted

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by uninstalling Android Studio and using the ADB built into LDPlayer. There were no restrictions

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).