# AVD Failed to Load ~ Failed to Parse Properties ~ Mac OSX

Tags: android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I'm going to say upfront, please forgive me. I'm a newbie to android development and fairly new to programming. Also on a Mac. You're going to have to talk...real...slow.

I can't get an AVD to load. I've tried it from Eclipse (Juno) and from the Android SDK Manager (20.0.3). Failed multiple times.

Received the same error each time,

> "Failed to parse properties from User/myname/.android/avd/nameIGaveEmulator/config.ini."

EDIT: I tried to solve the path problem on my own by checking folders and moving them around to be in the same folder, then resetting the path in Eclipse preferences, but that didn't work, so I trashed everything except for the zip files, uncompressed and started the entire installation all over again. When I opened up SDK Manager and attempted to download tools and platforms, however, I received the following. I'd forgotten that I received it on the first install. Would this have something to do with the problem?

> Preparing to install archives
>      Downloading Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 14
>      Installing Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 14
>      **Stopping ADB server failed (code -1).**
>      Installed Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 14
>      Stopping ADB server succeeded.
>      **Starting ADB server failed (code 255).**
>      Done. 1 package installed.

Sidenotes:

1. When I open Eclipse and SDK Manager, I don't see anyplace to check that I'm the administrator.
2. If a path needs to be "changed" what exactly does that mean and how do I go about doing so? Is it simply a matter of moving folders and files into the "correct" locations and then trying to load an AVD again?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703550/my-eclipse-adb-server-didnt-ack-failed-to-start-daemon

Comment: Any luck?  I get all sorts of problems running the ADB on my mac, including, "Starting ADB server failed (code 255)."  Figure anything out?

Answer (score 2):

Using command line, navigate to the /tools folder in your android SDK, then use the command:

$ ./android avd

This will launch the AVD manager.