# ADB Server didn't ACK, failed to start daemon

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

From the previous solved question: [Eclipse error "ADB server didn't ACK, failed to start daemon"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703550/my-eclipse-adb-server-didnt-ack-failed-to-start-daemon) , I've tested with the solution posted but it still doesn't solve my problem.
[image]

It seems that ADB was never started and I've tried to restart eclipse as well as detached my phone but still no luck. May I know what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error as following:

---

adb: ADB server didn't ACK
adb: * failed to start daemon *

### ddms: 'C:\Users\samsung\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe,start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary

So i followed the link to the adb.exe file and i run it manually, and it worked.

Also i killed the adb.exe from the task manager, and killed also another file that i can't recall its name but it ends with the word daemon.

Now both my lollipop and Kitkat versions are working probably. Hope that helpes
Note: for the phone with KitKat, i even did not install the USB driver, as it seems that windows 8.1 had figured it by him self.

Comment: "another file that i can't recall its name but it ends with the word daemon" is a bit vague for an answer. Please provide a more detailed explanation of how you solved this problem and if possible, provide some source to back up you experience.

Comment: Every time I kill-server, it starts itself on same port, and the error persists. Emulator never starts. I checked using sudo lsof -i <port>, there is a new pid for adb each time you kill server.