# ADB server didn't Acknowledge

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I could not run the android application never on my laptop. Eclipse gives same error constantly, that is "ADB server didn't Acknowledge"

I've tried everything, restart adb from ddms view, from command line (kill-server, start-server), from task manager and restart eclipse. When I manage to start adb server and re-open eclipse, as soon as I run the android application, same error comes to console; ADB server didn't ack.

Could you give an idea except restarting adb

Comment: you are trying to run the app on a phone or emulator?

Comment: if you are using Genymotion here is one solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703550/my-eclipse-adb-server-didnt-ack-failed-to-start-daemon

Answer (score 8):

For Mac users, what worked for me was:

1. Open Activity Monitor (equivalent to Windows task manager)
2. Kill the adb task
3. Restart adb

Answer (score 4):

Please kill adb by command:

```
taskkill /f /im "adb.exe"
```

then, re-start it with command:

```
adb start-server
```

It work very fine for me :)

Answer (score 2):

Look for typos in the ~/.android/adb_usb.ini file. This problem can be caused if that file gets messed up.

Comment: `rm -r ~/.android` fixed my issue. Thank you for cluing me in!

Answer (score 1):

In my pc, i use the command line taskkill /f /t /im wandoujia_daemon.exe (because  adb.exe or bas_daemon.exe is not running in my task manager) 
And... the adb server is started succesfully

Answer (score 0):

In addition to **@maveňツ** solution.

Actually we have to kill the process using this address `0.0.0.0:0`, that's why for most of the people killing `adb.exe` from task manager was working (In my case I was not able to see it even Task Manager).

Following the **@maveňツ** steps I find out that some other process was using this address.
I went ahead to kill it, it gave me `ACCESS DENIED` as `Error`.

So using the `tasklist|findstr ****` i find out the name of the process and killed it from task manager.

There after it started working.

In my case `bas_daemon` and `bas_helper` were using this address both of which corresponds to [MOBOROBO](http://www.moborobo.com/products/moborobo.html)

Answer (score 0):

in my case i use the command line `taskkill /f /t /im bas_deamon.exe` (because adb.exe was not started) and adb server is started successfully

Answer (score 0):

Kill ADB from command prompt.
Kill eclipse also from command prompt.
Start adb server from there using [**adb start-server**]
And start again.

Answer (score -1):

I believed you've checked the port number, and restart adb. But have you install proper android driver on your computer. Some universal android driver may not work on your computer, you'd better installed the driver provided by your mobile manufacturer, if you can't find the driver on manufacturer's website, consider download its software suit, it may include the driver.