# adb server is out of date. killing... cannot bind 'tcp:5037' ADB server didn't ACK * failed to start daemon * in ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adb, genymotion

I could not run the android application never on my laptop. Eclipse gives same error constantly, that is "ADB server didn't ack"

When I manage to start adb server and re-open eclipse, as soon as I run the android application, same error comes to console; ADB server didn't ack.

Could you give an idea except restarting adb

Comment: see this link

[ADB server didn't ack][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26217093/2169192

Comment: possible duplicate of [ADB server didn't ACK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26217055/adb-server-didnt-ack)

Comment: just follow my this answer I think it can resolve your problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757191/adb-and-genymotion-error-adb-server-is-out-of-date-killing-cannot-bind-tc/37152245#37152245

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to set the path of your SDK's adb into Genymotion. By default, Genymotion uses its own ADB tool (for many reasons). If the both binaries are not compatible (if your Android SDK platform tools or Genymotion has not been updated for a while) this problem happens.

To solve it you can define a specific one from the Android SDK. To specify a custom ADB tool:

1. Open Genymotion > Settings > ADB.
2. Check Use custom Android SDK tools.
3. Specify the path to the Android SDK by clicking Browse.
4. Click OK.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I get this problem only when a Genymotion's virtual device is running.

Answer (score 14):

update the adb to 1.0.32 if you have 1.0.31 or lower

```
adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31
wget -O - https://skia.googlesource.com/skia/+archive/cd048d18e0b81338c1a04b9749a00444597df394/platform_tools/android/bin/linux.tar.gz | tar -zxvf - adb
sudo mv adb /usr/bin/adb
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/adb
adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the final cause for me.

Comment: my adb version already updated to 1.0.32, but still its not working.

Answer (score 8):

for me the problem was that I am trying to use 2 adb processes

```
sudo apt-get remove adb android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

then go to your sdk and run `./adb start-server`

Answer (score 4):

Just Try this out !!!

Issue kill and start command in \platform-tools\

```
C:\sdk\platform-tools>adb kill-server
C:\sdk\platform-tools>adb start-server
```

Go to your specified sdk in this case here i have use C:\sdk but you must go the place where SDK and kill servers.

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Sometime, like it or not. The command "adb kill-server" have not effect.

So, please try other way

```
taskkill /f /im "adb.exe"
adb start-server
timeout 5
adb devices
pause
```

Copy it to notepad and save them with extension is ".bat"

ex: re-start.bat

Now, you can restart adb very quickly by double click to file !!!

Answer (score 1):

For users of Genymotion, just  do this:

```
ps aux | grep adb
```

Then look at */home/root/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb*.

Copy and paste it to your terminal:

```
exa:-   /home/buffer/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb   devices
```

Hopefully you will see:

```
your ip address:5555    device
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overview! Please take the [tour!] You might want to format your answer so that it is easier to read. Also, please specify why this answer is better/different from the other older answers (one of them was already accepted as a correct answer)

Answer (score 0):

Faced the Same Issue,  doing the below steps it worked fine

```
sudo cp /home/username/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb /usr/bin/adb
```

---

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/adb
```

---

that's it after this your adb will work fine