# ADB issues with genymotion

Tags: android, connection, adb

Since I updated the SDK 23.0.2 and AndroidStudio 1.4 I got issues accessing the genymotion emulator over ADB. 
Here is what my linux machine does:

```
pepperonas@pepperonas-Allstar ~/IdeaProjects/Android/TruthOrDare $ adb uninstall com.pepperonas.truthordare
adb server is out of date.  killing...
cannot bind 'tcp:5037'
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
- waiting for device -
adb server is out of date.  killing...
cannot bind 'tcp:5037'
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: 
adb server is out of date.  killing...
* daemon started successfully *
- waiting for device -
adb server is out of date.  killing...
* daemon started successfully *
adb server is out of date.  killing...
cannot bind 'tcp:5037'
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
- waiting for device -
adb server is out of date.  killing...
cannot bind 'tcp:5037'
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: device '(null)' not found
adb server is out of date.  killing...
cannot bind 'tcp:5037'
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
- waiting for device -
adb server is out of date.  killing...
cannot bind 'tcp:5037'
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: device '(null)' not found
adb server is out of date.  killing...
cannot bind 'tcp:5037'
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
- waiting for device -
adb server is out of date.  killing...
cannot bind 'tcp:5037'
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: device '(null)' not found
adb server is out of date.  killing...
cannot bind 'tcp:5037'
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
- waiting for device -
adb server is out of date.  killing...
cannot bind 'tcp:5037'
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: device '(null)' not found
adb server is out of date.  killing...
^C
pepperonas@pepperonas-Allstar ~/IdeaProjects/Android/TruthOrDare $
```

Not very useful but maybe somebody knows what goes wrong... Even a reboot (emulator AND computer) doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set your Android sdk path into the Genymotion settings.

Comment: are you sure you did it like explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31488197/adb-server-is-out-of-date-killing-cannot-bind-tcp5037-adb-server-didnt-a/31498728#31498728 ? Sorry to insist but I'm supprised it does not solve the problem.