# adb versionadb server is out of date. killing... cannot bind 'tcp:5037' ADB server didn't ACK * failed to start daemon * error:

Tags: android, adb

When i try to connect device `adb connect 192.168.1.22` then I get below error in command prompt

```
adb server is out of date.  killing...
cannot bind 'tcp:5037'
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error:
```

I tried two solution but not work...

[adb server is out of date. killing... cannot bind 'tcp:5037' ADB server didn't ACK * failed to start daemon * in ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31488197/adb-server-is-out-of-date-killing-cannot-bind-tcp5037-adb-server-didnt-a)

[ADB and Genymotion error: "adb server is out of date. killing... cannot bind 'tcp:5037' ADB server didn't ACK"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757191/adb-and-genymotion-error-adb-server-is-out-of-date-killing-cannot-bind-tc)

my current adb version is

```
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32
```

anyone know how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to keep multiple copies of `adb` in sync - delete all copies but the one in the `sdk\platform-tools` folder. Then update the `platform-tools` package to the latest version using SDK Manager.

Comment: hello alex already latest version is there

Comment: *Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32* is far from being the latest

Comment: ok thanx let me update

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `adb` you calling from command line and the one specified in Genymotion are from the same Android SDK version as used in your IDE (it should be running when you experiencing the issue)

Comment: how can check , can you explain more

Comment: Check paths to Android SDK in IDE's settings and Genymotion's settings to match and verify that you are running adb command from the path with command `which adb` if you are not on Windows. If you're running Windows see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-the-windows-command-line

Comment: i am using ubuntu not windows