# React-Native, Android, Genymotion: ADB server didn't ACK

Tags: android, react-native, genymotion

I am working with React-Native, Android, and Genymotion on Mac. When I run `react-native run-android` I get this lines at the end of the launch operation:

```
...
04:54:40 E/adb: error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: Address already in use
04:54:40 E/adb: ADB server didn't ACK
04:54:40 E/ddms: '/Users/paulbrie/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb,start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
04:54:40 E/adb: * failed to start daemon *
04:54:40 E/adb: error: cannot connect to daemon
:app:installDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: Timeout getting device list.
...
```

However, `adb devices` returns this:

```
List of devices attached
192.168.59.101:5555 device
```

So far I've found no solution to run my app on the emulator. Has anyone encountered the same issue?

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: This error can happen regardless of Genymotion running.

Answer (score 322, accepted):

After more research I've realized that Genymotion uses by default its own adb.

[image]

I switched to my main adb (the same used by react-native) and it solved the issue. I guess that because Genymotion's adb was launched first I got the  `Address already in use` error message.

Comment: Thank you for posting this. I nearly had a heart attack, i updated my android studios 2.1 to Preview 3 last night and genymotion will not connect anymore. This helped me to solve it.

Comment: I tried this solution, but I still got the same error. Are there alternate solutions?

Comment: @user2254679 did you check this thread as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703550/my-eclipse-adb-server-didnt-ack-failed-to-start-daemon?rq=1

Comment: @Paul could you please elaborate on what path you are providing? where is this *adb* located which is used by react-native? I am trying to provide the path of my Android SDK but it is not working. in English would be best.

Comment: @KPal, the path is specific to your own setup. In my case it was the standard path from the Android installation in Mac at that time: `/Users/$yourName/Library/Android/sdk`. If you installed Android you should search for your path given the Android version / your platform.

Comment: "I switched to my main adb" - what does this even mean?

Answer (score 46):

I am using genymotion, but Paul's solution alone did not fix the error (for Mac).

I had to:

**Update Android SDK to the latest version (24.4.1) via the SDK manager**

Type `android` in the command line

In the SDK manager find the latest SDK tools and install.

Once installed the SDK path should update the new SDK location like below.

[image]

**Then update the $ANDROID_HOME to use the new SDK**

`export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1`

`export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`

Confirm it has been added by viewing your path with `echo $PATH`

**Then in genymotion do what @Paul says above and point genymotion ADB to use the same sdk**

[image]

Comment: It works for ubuntu 16.04. For some reason i thought `$ANDROID_HOME/tools` directory would not be necessary on the classpath. You need to add to connect to adb.

Answer (score 10):

**System:** Windows 10

**My issue:** Setting Genymotion to point to the custom SDK didn't have any affect. I still received the:

> Couldn't start project on Android: could not install smartsocket
>   listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:5037: Only one usage of each socket
>   address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (10048)
>   could not read ok from ADB Server * failed to start daemon * error:
>   cannot connect to daemon

What I discovered was there was a difference in ADB versions being used throughout the system. Here is the command I used to find them:

```
where /r C:\ adb.exe
```

This produced the results:

```
C:\Program Files\Expo XDE\resources\app\node_modules\xdl\binaries\windows\adb\adb.exe
C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion\tools\adb.exe
C:\Users\kyle\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
C:\Users\kyle\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb backup\adb.exe
```

Navigating to each directory and running:

```
adb.exe version
```

Allowed me to see that Expo was running ADB version:

```
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.36
Revision fd9e4d07b0f5-android
```

While Genymotion using the custom SDK had version (c:\Users\kyle\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe):

```
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
Revision 3db08f2c6889-android
```

As a test I took the adb files (adb.exe, AdbWinApi.dll, AdbWinUsbApi.dll) from

```
c:\Users\kyle\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
```

and placed them into a backup folder. I then moved the adb files located at

```
c:\Program Files\Expo XDE\resources\app\node_modules\xdl\binaries\windows\adb\adb.exe
```

into that same location. I killed adb with:

```
adb kill-server
```

which caused a restart of the adb server automatically due to having my Genymotion device already running. I hit the "Restart" button inside of the Expo XDE and it immediately began working. Here is the log where I hit the restart button at 1:13:04 AM:

```
12:45:53 AM
could not install *smartsocket* listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:5037: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (10048)
could not read ok from ADB Server
* failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon
1:13:04 AM
Restarting project and clearing packager cache (Hold shift while clicking restart to avoid clearing cache).
1:13:11 AM
Starting React Native packager...
1:13:17 AM
Scanning 543 folders for symlinks in C:\Users\kyle\git\betalog\node_modules (49ms)
1:13:17 AM
1:13:19 AM
Couldn't adb reverse: closed
1:13:20 AM
Project opened! You can now use the "Share" or "Device" buttons to view your project.
1:13:26 AM
Couldn't adb reverse: closed
1:13:26 AM
Downloading latest version of Expo
1:13:28 AM
Installing Expo on device
1:13:33 AM
Opening on Android device
1:13:56 AM
Building JavaScript bundle: finished in 59643ms.
1:14:01 AM
Dependency graph loaded.
1:14:03 AM
Your JavaScript transform cache is empty, rebuilding (this may take a minute).
```

**Conclusion:** Genymotion and Expo may need to use the same version of adb so that Expo can properly communicate with the simulated device. Pointing Genymotion to your android SDK location as well as ensuring Expo XDE has that same version will allow correct communication between devices. I moved the Expo XDE version to the SDK location, but you might be able to go the other way (take the sdk ADB files and place them in the Expo XDE resource location).

**P.S.** I've been all through the stackoverflow posts related to this issue. Just so you guys know my task manager shows three instances of adb.exe running. If you kill any of them they just come back.

Hope this helps /cheers

Answer (score 9):

Maybe your adb versions are mismatching

Check:

```
adb version
```

Then:

```
cd /Path/to/Android/Sdk/platform-tools && ./adb version
```

If these two are different you have an error here, just remove adb from sys and copy the one that is in platform-tools to /usr/bin/

Answer (score 5):

the adb version on your system is different from the adb version on the android sdk platform-tools .
Below suggestion is work for me for Linux operating system

1. check sys adb version run the below command

> adb version

Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39

2. check sdk adb version

> cd /root/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
>
> ./adb version

Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32

3. copy

> rm /usr/bin/adb

[Note : the above command remove the existing adb then copy the adb from sdk/platform-tools directory ]

> sudo cp /root/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb /usr/bin/adb

Then run the project using this command

> react-native run-android

Comment: this is a good solution for Linux, it works with or without android studio installed

Answer (score 4):

If want to keep your system clean, you can also **use Genymotion without Android Studio**:

1. Find Genymotion's copy of `adb`. On macOS this is normally `/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/tools/`.
2. Add the Genymotion tools directory to your path - execute/add the line `export PATH=/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/tools/:$PATH` to your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_rc`.
3. Make sure that you can run adb from your terminal.

(From https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/genymotion)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same thing while I tried to run from expo UI. 
Did the same things, as described in answers, but app was not running.
When once tried run `exp android` from command line (in the project folder), application ran successfully and next times runs from Expo UI was successfully.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue.

First, I uninstalled the app.
Then, I pointed GenyMotion to the android sdk provided from Android Studio
Next, I ran "adb kill-server" into the terminal.
Finally, I re-ran "react-native run-android" and got a build success.

Answer (score 2):

The steps worked for me are :

- **$ adb kill-server**
- **$ adb start-server**
- **$ cd android**
- **$ ./gradlew clean**
- **$ cd ..**
- **$ react-native run-android**

Answer (score 2):

**For Ubuntu**

It works for me!!

1. check sys adb version

> adb version

Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39

2 check sdk adb version

> cd /home/user_name/Android/sdk/platform-tools
>
> ./adb version

Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32

3. copy

> sudo cp /home/user_name/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb /usr/local/bin

that's all! It will work  now.

Answer (score 1):

1.use custom sdk path in genymotion.(Suppose this one won't work means,Try to execute the second one)

2.Manually use this command to execute(SDK PATH/adb she
ll am start -n/Package name/MainActivity).

**C:\Users\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/platform-tools/adb she
ll am start -n com.example/com.example.ManiActivity**

And try to run the application by using react-native run-android.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue happened when I try to run my react-native project in Genymotion

For Linux ubuntu 20.04
Go to `/home/mycomputer/Android/Sdk/platorm-tools`

run `$./adb version`

just copy the adb path in `/usr/bin`

`$ sudo cp /home/raik/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb /usr/bin`

Then I can run my project in genymotion.

Note: In some Linux system may be copied to this path /usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 0):

If someone is facing this issue in Windows with Android Studio emulator then just run following command in powershell or cmd:

```
taskkill /F /IM adb.exe
```

It should kill all the adb process instances and then you can Reload the app or Start the App on Android again via Expo CLI.