# How to set the default Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion, nativescript

I am building an app with [NativeScript](https://www.nativescript.org/), where I run:

```
$ tns run android --emulator
```

to build the app and launch it in an emulator. When I do this, the default android emulator boots on my machine, which is unusably slow...

In all the demos, they are using the Genymotion Emulator. I have installed this, but the NativeScript command still launches the default emulator. How do I get this to launch on the genymotion emulator?

NB: I am using Windows 10

## Update:

Even if I run the command with the Genymotion emulator running (and nothing else), I get the following log output and a new terminal window is opened running `android-sdk/tools/emulator-arm.exe`

> BUILD SUCCESSFUL
>
> Total time: 11.959 secs
>
> Project successfully built.
>
> Using  C:\Users\George\Source\Repos\NativeScript-App\Bluetooth\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\bluetoothdemo-debug.apk
>
> Starting Android emulator with image Xamarin_Android_API_23

That looks as though it is referencing the emulator I had been using when I was developing with Xamarin. Any ideas where I can change that, or why that is being called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

start Genymotion, then start one of the devices that you have setup in Genymotion

then check that the device is seen:
`$ tns device`

then run nativescript like so
`$tns run android --geny 192.111.222.33:555`

(or whatever is the name that you get from the `tns device` command)

Answer (score 2):

To my experience `--emulator` always tries to start the stock emulators. Try to start genymotion and then just `tns run android` (w/o the `--emulator` option).

Answer (score 1):

I think it does that when there is no emulator running.

Try starting Genymotion first, launch the image you want, then run the "tns run adroid" command.

Comment: I am afraid not, even if I only have the genymotion software and then run that command, I still get the android emulator launching. I'll add more details to the question.

Comment: I have added the details to my question, any ideas?

Comment: My recommendation was to use the "tns run android" without the --emulator flag.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

To use GenyMotion by default, first delete all the Android emulators using

```
android avd
```

I then followed the solution on this thread:
[React-Native, Android, Genymotion: ADB server didn't ACK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35959350/react-native-android-genymotion-adb-server-didnt-ack)

Edit the settings in GenyMotion to use the android SDK you downloaded. (path for Windows is  Users/YOUR-SYSTEM/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk)

You still have to run the device on GenyMotion before running the emulator

```
tns run android
```