# react-native run-android DeviceException Could not create ADB Bridge

Tags: android, react-native, genymotion

I have created a React-Native project. When I run `react-native run-ios`, the build succeeds. But when I run `react-native run-android` I get this error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: Could not create ADB Bridge. ADB location: /Applications/ADT/sdk/platform-tools/adb
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have also fixed using following URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35959350/react-native-android-genymotion-adb-server-didnt-ack

Answer (score 17):

I have solve it, The error is because Genymotion use its own SDK not custom SDK location.I solved this question with the URL follow:

[React-Native, Android, Genymotion: ADB server didn't ACK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35959350/react-native-android-genymotion-adb-server-didnt-ack)

thanks for Simon!

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this, I came to this topic from a Yahoo search and your post here led me to the solution

Comment: What if you're not using genymotion?

Answer (score 12):

If you have issue while building your project using **react-native run-android**
and 
build failed with an exception of not creating adb bridge.

solution:

Go to your project path or any path in command prompt and type :
**adb kill-server** 
after it again build your project using react-native run-android

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It worked great, but I would like to understand why. What is adb? What happens when the 'adb kill-server' cmd is used?

Comment: Hi @Grez.Kev, please check that link(https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb).
'adb kill-server' kills the system abd service which is running in background.

Answer (score 2):

Press CTRL+SHIFT+ESC to open the Task Manager and delete the ADB.EXE process

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your device over usb for development then it is an error of your adb path.. set the path to D:\Android\sdk\platform-tools... in pc properties->advanced settings->environment variables->system variables..it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal

1. Go to android sdk path =>

   `c:\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools`
2. Enter the following commands:

   `adb kill-server && adb start-server`

Answer (score 0):

i accidentally added adb path directly in environmental variables with name
adb instead of **Path**, when i remove it, this error resolved.