# Getting issues with ADB for react-native run-android

Tags: java, android, react-native, adb, emulation

I've been trying to follow the react-native tutorial on udemy, but I've been having trouble getting started: When I try to run the react-native run-android, I've been getting this error:

```
app:installDebug FAILEDnstallDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: Could not create ADB Bridge. 
ADB location: C:\Users\(USERNAME)\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
```

I've been using the latest android studio client; I have been using an emulator to simulate a Google Nexus 5, and using the java version that is compatible for the project (the latest, 9.0.9, has been causing problems). I have no familiarity with Genymotion, as it has not been mentioned in the class or is said to be a necessary application; any solutions involving this has not been of any use so far.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I think you will find what you are looking for here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36769699/react-native-run-android-deviceexception-could-not-create-adb-bridge

Comment: I have seen this thread before; the issue is related to the use of genymotion. The problem though is that I am not using it, neither its SDK nor its emulator. I have tried the other solutions (kill adb server), but they didn't work.

Comment: The issue with android emulator.Changed the AVD settings to enable "Use Host GPU" in android emulator.