# The react-native project does not start

Tags: android, node.js, react-native

I create my first project node js using expo init and when I try to run it I get an error.
Also, I tried to create a project using react-native init, and also get an error.
Below I have added screenshots of errors.
I follow the instructions from here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.

[Error using expo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SFgj.png)

[Error using react-native init](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50R9v.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36769699/react-native-run-android-deviceexception-could-not-create-adb-bridge

Comment: Looks like you haven't setup Android SDK properly. Open android studio and sync your project. You would identify the problems over there.

Answer (score 0):

1.First of All, In your devices You should be open developer options  in your devices.

Comment: I use an emulator

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. Someone might find my decision helpful. The first time I installed the Node version 12.11.1 (includes npm 6.11.3). The second time, I deleted the Node and contents of the C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm folder, and installed the version 10.16.3(includes npm 6.9.0). And now it works.