# adb server didn't ACK while working on MAC

Tags: android, appium

I am running my android appium execution on MAC machine.

I have installed android studio and have set the path variable.

While executing `adb start-server` I got below error:

> adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
>
> error: could not install smartsocket listener: Address already in use
>
> ADB server didn't ACK
>
> failed to start daemon
>
> error: cannot connect to daemon

Firewall setting is turned OFF and no other `ADB` present like `GenyMotion`.

Comment: if the server doesn´t ACK on your MAC it seems to be a LACK and you should look at this FACT (boww, bum bum bum, booww): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35959350/react-native-android-genymotion-adb-server-didnt-ack

Comment: I am not using Genymotion. Only Android-studio

Comment: ok, that was in my case some time ago. So, do you see the adb.exe in your task manager?

Comment: No, nothing in my Activity Monitor also

Comment: I am not sure but try to kill the adb server in your sdk directory with for example: `C:\sdk\platform-tools>adb kill-server` (depends on your path) and restart it via `C:\sdk\platform-tools>adb start-server` .....does this work?

Comment: otherwise, maybe the setting of your path variable is not correct. If it doesn´t work, please post the path variable...

Comment: No it didn't worked.. I tried "adb version" and it listed the version correctly: "Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.36"

Comment: For "adb devices" it displayed the same error:                                                  List of devices attached
adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: Address already in use
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon

Comment: then the only thing I can imagine is that adb is not up to date. Open the sdk manager and be sure everything is with the latest version...

Comment: Today again I have re-installed everything...so its new version only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115300/discussion-between-rishi-khanna-and-opiatefuchs).

Answer (score 0):

Did you set android sdks, platform-tools and tools path in your bash_profiles? Or Could you navigate to android sdks path and try to execute adb start-server command? If you are running appium from appium app then I would recommend to set android sdks path in settings.

Comment: This is what my bash file holds for android home:                                         export PATH=/Users/Admin/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:~/.android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/

Comment: Are you using 2 different android sdks? Root path for platform-tools and tools should be same. 

export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/Admin/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/Admin/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/Admin/Library/Android/sdk/tools

I think because of different platform-tools bash is getting confused. I recommend to use one path only. Also, if using appium app, set android sdks path in settings.

Comment: Yes did that.. still same issue

Comment: If you navigate to your add location (/Users/Admin/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools) and execute the ads start-server command, do you still get error?

Comment: I tried starting adb in different port using: adb -P 8345 start-server and server successfully started in this port but "adb devices" is returning empty list of devices

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415746/how-to-resolve-the-adb-server-didnt-ack-error