# why i cant see any devices in my android studio play button

Tags: android, android-studio

When I hit `run app`, it opens the `select deployment target` and in many times even when I have the genymotion open, it doesn`t show anything. Even with my celphone connected. Sometimes it shows, but must of the times it doesnt then I have to restart the android studio and get lucky. Please, Im freaking out with this because I cant find a solution for it.

Is there something I can do?

Comment: Maybe try to kill and restart the try  adb server adb kill-server and adb restart-server. You need to have the android sdk tools added to your PATH

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Killing and restarting AS didnt help. Same issue. When I hit `adb server` on the AS terminal, i get the following: error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:5037: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (10048)
could not read ok from ADB Server
* could not start server *`

Im a newbie in android development and AS. I searched for it on google and found a topic telling me to change the path on genymotion. I did it and now I can see the devices. Thanks!

Comment: But do you know why Im still geting this error with adb server?

Answer (score 1):

Quit/close Android Studio and restart it.

Note: I've also tried just restarting adb from terminal but that's had less success than just killing AS and restarting it.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but quiting and closing didn`t help. I could solve the problem by going to the genymotion > settings > ADB > changed the Android SDK path, it was on the default. I dont know if this will fix on future attempts, I will just wait to see if it really fixes.

Comment: For what this is worth I'm also running the beta channel version of AS. It's really nice too, I'd recommend trying it. http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/2-2-beta

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution at:

[React-Native, Android, Genymotion: ADB server didn't ACK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35959350/react-native-android-genymotion-adb-server-didnt-ack)

Changed the path of genymotion`s Android SDK.

I dont know if this solution is temporary, so maybe when I close AS and restart I may across the same issue.

Thanks!