# React Native Could not create ADB Bridge Error

Tags: android-studio, react-native, adb

JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/0.20.1/react-native-0.20.1.pom
....# a bunch of downloads here
:app:assembleDebug
:app:installDebug
05:13:20 E/adb: Unable to obtain result of 'adb version'
                                                         :app:installDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.

  > com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: Could not create ADB Bridge. ADB location: D:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

I'm using Windows machine and the android studio and have followed the tutorial over at
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
I'm stuck at this as i cannot run the 'react-native run-android' on command prompt

Also, running adb version gives

Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32
Revision eac51f2bb6a8-android

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: is windows 32bit?..... had similar problem in ubuntu 14.04(32 bit) refer this https://askubuntu.com/questions/714653/adb-android-studio-ubuntu-error-unable-to-detect-adb-version-adb-output-hom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved this problem ..if you are using emulator then follow [React-Native, Android, Genymotion: ADB server didn't ACK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35959350/react-native-android-genymotion-adb-server-didnt-ack)... if you are using your device over usb for development then it is an error of your adb path.. set the path to D:\Android\sdk\platform-tools... in pc properties->advanced settings->environment variables->system variables..it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have another solution, If you are using emulator then make sure its running before you start you react native app. Some time you may need to close the application(like skype) those are using same port:8081(default used by react native application) before running react native app.