# Cannot run android app using expo and genymotion

Tags: react-native, genymotion, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-2.3, expo

[image: expo]

I am use genymotion along with expo to run my react-native app. I am not getting any errors with genymotion, but when i try to run it with expo, i get the following error:

**Couldn't start project on Android: could not install *smartsocket* listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:5037: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (10048)
could not read ok from ADB Server
* failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon**

I don't have vt-x enabled in my system so Android 5 and above versions are not working. This I am trying to run using Custom tablet 4.2.2-API 17 - 1536x2048.
[image]

Please guide me on how to proceed!

UPDATE : @dikaiosune here is the output of `adb devices`
[image]

Comment: Can you paste the output of `adb devices` on this machine?

Comment: Any news? for this, Im having the same problem

Comment: Getting the same error here.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing this issue on my Windows 10 laptop. Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45456154/145122), this is what I've done:

- In Genymotion, open settings
- In the tab ADB, browse the ADB.EXE located deep inside the EXPO installation folder. See image below
- Go back to EXPO and click on the device button and open in Android.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I changed my genymotion adb folder to this `C:\Users\<account-name>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\xdl\binaries\windows\adb` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

ubuntu 16.04

Remove any adb you may have.

sudo apt remove adb

Add to your ~/.basrc :

```
export ANDROID_HOME='Path to Android SDK'
export PATH=$PATH:'Your Genymotion Directory/tools/'
```

The last one gonna add 'adb' from genymotion to your path.

PS: Don't forget to close and reopen your terminal.

It worked for me, was facing the same problem. 
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and AirServer worked for me. The steps are:

1. Install AirServer on your laptop
2. Install AirServer mobile app on your mobile
3. Now after running the project through your expo client app on mobile, just open your AirServer mobile app and scan the code or open the link and here your native app is running on your laptop.

Answer (score -1):

My ADB.exe was present at:
C:/Users/hp/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/binaries/windows/adb

I changed to this and it worked fine.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxkuF.png)

Answer (score -3):

tns run android --emulator specifically targets the Android SDK emulator.
You have two options to use Genymotion:

Start the Genymotion virtual device and never close it. Then remove the --emulator parameter, like tns run android
use the --geny parameter, like: tns run android --emulator --geny . You can also use the shorter emulate command, like tns emulate android --geny 
For more details, you can refer to our online help at any time using tns help run android.

Hope this helps!