# [Android][react-native-run-android] app: installDebug error:shellCommands unresponsive

Tags: emulation, react-native

I am trying to build a small app in react native using android studio emulator. I found this issue when I tried react-native run-android.https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY7br.png

Comment: Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35959350/react-native-android-genymotion-adb-server-didnt-ack