# Unable to run Ionic app

Tags: android, ionic-framework, adb

I am unable to run my Ionic app in --livereload mode. It gives me an error as:

```
   Error: C:\softwares\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
   error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:5037: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (10048)
   could not read ok from ADB Server
   * failed to start daemon *
   error: cannot connect to daemon
```

I started task manager and found 3 adb server are running.I tried to kill them but unable to do that. Please help.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=184713

Comment: its not working for me

Comment: please provide another one solution

Comment: type `adb devices` in you **cmd** and tell wethere you are able to detect your device or not

Comment: https://cithukyaw.wordpress.com/2016/03/12/adb-server-didnt-ack-or-adb-server-is-out-of-date-killing/ check this and also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703550/my-eclipse-adb-server-didnt-ack-failed-to-start-daemon hope it will solve your issue

Comment: List of devices attached
adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:5037: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (10048)
could not read ok from ADB Server
* failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon

Comment: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/android-wont-connect-windows-adb-fix-it-three-steps/

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem while running application with genymotion. I gave the custom path of my sdk in adb settings in configuration of genymotion. And it worked for me.
Also same problem occurs if there is duplication of sdk paths.So you should also check your environment variables for that.