# regarding error in starting DDMS

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation, ddms

i have eclipse Galileo, SDK, and android on my system, the problem is that when i run eclipse,sometimes it runs and sometimes it says "failed to initialize Monitor Thread", unable to establish Loopback connection....and the console in eclipse says:"ADB server didn't acknowledge, failed to start daemon", please help, all the API's are installed in eclipse, and sdk is proper. the same DDMS runs sometimes and sometimes not. I have even tried to run adb server using the command prompt , i even closed the eclipse and then kill the adb server and restarted the elipse 
but still the error persist.
 Running adb kill-server and adb start-server yields the same message "ADB Server didn't ACK" 
i read somewhere in the same site:
1. goto tools folder of your android sdk
2. run `emulator.exe -avd <your avd>`. it will take some time for the emulator to run.
3. Once you see the homescreen on your emulator, open eclipse and run your program again...
 i tried this, the emulator started running but no output of my program and the same error on restarting the eclipse as mentioned above, kindly suggest some remedy

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adb won't start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306322/adb-wont-start)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your firewall.somethimes it may happens for this

Comment: okay, but please state clearly what settings should i actually check, i don't have clear idea about this.....

Comment: See whether Firewall is on/off.If on make it Off and restart eclipse