# Android ADB didn't ack issue in eclipse

Tags: android, adb

I have spent around 5 hrs on this problem. I have read the same question on stackoverflow, but none of the solutions solved my problem...
**First, it gives me:**

```
[2013-02-28 14:48:21 - adb] ADB server didn't ACK
[2013-02-28 14:48:21 - adb] * failed to start daemon *
```

To solve that, I kill the adb.exe in task manager, restart eclipse. Then go to DDMS, reset adb. NO LUCK...

**Then, I go to command line window, type `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`, it gives me:**

```
adb server is out of date. killing...
ADB server didn't ACK
fail to start deamon
```

Now I don't know what to do. I have a project to develop on eclipse, so really need to solve this problem soon. Someone please help!!

(As many solution indicated, I killed my adb.exe thousands of times, but it showed up immediately in task manager after 2 seconds. )

Comment: Try adb devices, what does it output? Also you can try to restart your computer.

Comment: Restart your PC this is the best option .:)

Comment: I have restart my computer and eclipse for quite many times, still no luck

Comment: @Jolin found [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=4913853&postcount=10)

Comment: weird thing is, it worked this morning, and suddenly the error appeared

Comment: my port 5037 is not in use... I m running out of ideas...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adb won't start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306322/adb-wont-start)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved the problem. 
Because I have a small assistant plugin installed on my pc, it has an adb.exe running in the background all the time. So after I uninstalled the plugin, the error has gone!

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem, here is what actually helped me:

1. Go to **platform-tools** in Android SDK directory.
2. Type:

   `adb nodaemon server`

   Output:

   `cannot bind 'tcp:5037'`
3. Now I know the reason adb not responsive is because it can not bind to port 5037. Use following command to find out the process that occupies the port:

   `netstat -ano | findstr 5037`

   Output:

   [image: Find port binding]
4. Note that process with PID 4888 is occupying port 5037.
5. Open **Task Manager**, click on **Details** tab, find the process and kill it, tfadb.exe in this case. it may vary for me it is sh.exe and port 4599 and delete all adb.exe

   [image: Processes]
6. Retry `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`, hopefully adb is up running fine.

   [image: Fine]

Answer (score 14):

Killing the process in the TASK MANAGER solves it in my case. After killing it run **adb start-server** or **adb devices** and you should be fine

Comment: This works regardless of the IDE you use and the OS you are working with. One good sign on when to kill the process is if you try to run commands on the device bridge and it take a long time to respond (like: "adb devices" or "adb kill-server", whick sometimes fails).

Answer (score 2):

I have an HTC device, whose driver software (HTC Sync) tried to run processes using adb at the same time that I was trying to run from Eclipse. If you have a program like HTC Sync for your device that might have been needed to install the driver, close this program to keep it from executing adb in parallel. So far for me, this has fixed it 100 percent.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when we are running **SnapPea**, it is running a background process called **"wandoujia_adb"**. when killing the process and running the command "adb start-server" in cmd promt, i get the following o/p text to cmd promt:

> C:\Users**>adb start-server
>       * daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
>       * daemon started successfully *

Answer (score 0):

Here Is your Solution

1. Kill ADB process
2. CLose Eclipse
3. Remove Lock File .metadata of workspace
4. Ensure Only one Java Whether JDK or JRE in installed
   if found remove the previous version
5. Use Ccleaner to remove Temp files
6. Clean Registry too
7. Restart the system
8. Restart Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

If you have your device connected and you are trying to test through an emulator, make sure that a device sync agent isnt running in the background. This relaunches the adb even after you kill it in task manager.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many approaches I've found here, but just one worked out perfectly:

UNINSTALL AVAST ANTIVIRUS!

Answer (score 0):

I had a mobogenie plugin installed on my machine which was continuously running adb. Uninstalled it and got the problem solved.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I was using the mobogeine universal driver, when I end task `adb.exe` from task manager, It restarts again in 1-2 seconds occupying another port number.

To get rid of this problem I have to disconnect my phone & 1st kill mobogeine driver, then `adb.exe` does not restarts agian.  Now  run `adb start-server` . If the success message shown then everything worked perfectly.