# The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured, ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am really frustrated with this problem, Please note that I read the following thread, but it does not help!:

[The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035456/the-connection-to-adb-is-down-and-a-severe-error-has-occurred)

[Android ADB didn't ack issue in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136252/android-adb-didnt-ack-issue-in-eclipse)

When I run my android application(firstly built):

```
[2014-10-01 15:13:09 - jizhang] ------------------------------
[2014-10-01 15:13:09 - jizhang] Android Launch!
[2014-10-01 15:13:09 - jizhang] The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
[2014-10-01 15:13:09 - jizhang] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
[2014-10-01 15:13:09 - jizhang] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'E:\Programming\ADT\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.
```

According to the threads, I do :

1.I do not find adb.exe in my process, so I can't kill it.

2.I have tried type `adb kill-server`, and the cmd says `server not running`

3.And then I type `adb start-server`,
but it says:

```
adb server is out of date, killing
ABD serevr didn't ACK 
*failed to start daemon*
```

4.And I confirm that my abd.exe is in E:\Programming\ADT\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools

I have tried restart eclipse and my computer(windows 7) serveral times!

Please help.

According to the second answer on [Android ADB didn't ack issue in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136252/android-adb-didnt-ack-issue-in-eclipse)

I type Type:

```
adb nodaemon server
```

Output:`cannot bind 'tcp:5037'`

and then `netstat -ano | findstr 5037`

two output:
[image]

But I can't find then in my taskManager 
[image]

So, i use taskkill /pid XXXX -f to kill it.

But when I kill it, and I found another pid occurs:

still at 127.0.0.1:5037 ...

I don't know what is that!!!Do I have a way to change the port of adb?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136252/android-adb-didnt-ack-issue-in-eclipse

Comment: @Arash , thank you!The first answer is the same as killing the process. The second answer seems fit but when I "netstat -ano | findstr 5037" I found two pid who comes out, 6728 and 7304, but I can't find them in my task manager!!!What]

Comment: what have you done just before this problem occures ?

Comment: @Months ago, when android L preview release , I upgrade the adt to 23 and some problems on adt(a bug ) accurs and then I download a new ADT and download things in sdk manager and I starts to program and found this problem!

Comment: try this [SO question answers](http://superuser.com/questions/215351/how-do-i-kill-a-process-that-is-dead-but-listening) to kill processes that still listen on 5037 port

Comment: @ashoke , I don't find the relative command and I use taskkill /pid XXXX -f , but I found another pid comes out uses the port.