# ddms: 'adb.exe,start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary, Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

My adb is down, no matter I am using ADT or Android Studio.

And according to the second answer [of this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136252/android-adb-didnt-ack-issue-in-eclipse), I did:

1. I type:

   ```
   adb nodaemon server
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   cannot bind 'tcp:5037'
   ```
2. Then `netstat -ano | findstr 5037`

   I did find a pid of 7416 who listen in `127.0.0.1:5037`
3. I use `taskkill /pid 7416 -f` to kill it.
4. I type `netstat -ano | findstr 5037` again, I found another pid listens at `127.0.0.1:5037` again!

I guess they are the same, but I have no idea who it is.

Can I simply have a easy way to release this port or change the adb port to another one?

Comment: Have you tried tasklist|findstr 5037 to find the name of the program at 5037?

Comment: What program is listening?  Is it an adb or something else?  If it's a one-time issue rebooting may work, otherwise you may have to figure out what is claiming that port.  In theory ADB could be patched to utilize a different one.

Comment: @ChrisStratton , I found that program!! And I kill it and stop it from booting, which solves this problem now.

Comment: I'm facing similar kind of issue can any one suggest me why this is happening

Comment: I think you might help this answer. Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47150042/6917362

Comment: need off VPN client

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I solve this problem at last! I finally found the program name of the pid and I kill it in the task manager.

The way to detect is described in the question:

1. adb nodaemon server

Output:

> cannot bind 'tcp:5037'

2.and then `netstat -ano | findstr 5037` to find who takes this port.

Get the pid and find it in the task manager. Please note that the process tab may not show the column of pid, we should include it by setting.

In my case, it is tfadb.exe who takes this port! This is a Chinese Video program client! Try to kill it in task manager.

Now I stop it starting from booting. The problem is solved.

Comment: Does the fact that it has "adb" in its name and uses port 5037 mean it's a tool for video on top of the ADB capability of an Android device?  Or is it purely coincidence?

Comment: @ChrisStratton , I Think it is just a terrible coincidence! This is an  program for windows not for android.

Comment: You may be able to change the port that program uses, or you can change the one ADB uses, either with an environment variable, or in recent versions a command line option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836571/changing-default-port-i-e-5037-on-which-adb-server-runs

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!! Literally tried solving this for 3 hours.

Answer (score 63):

In my case I was trying to use genymotion emulator device.
With genymotion opened and running, I've tried to run my app in this emulator but I it doesn't worth

In this part I had this error:

```
'C:\Users\Jose\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe,start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
```

Then I've tried Jaskey's solution but it doesn't works.

So I stopped genymotion emulator. 
Then I restart ADB (Tools > Android > Unchecked Unable ADB Integration then I've checked again)

Next I've start genymotion emulator again
And now the app works on the emulator.

Comment: This way worked for me in a very first trial. Thank you.

Answer (score 61):

For Windows,

Close Android Studio and any of your Emulators you are using,

then goto->TaskManager and Kill the process(adb.exe)

After finishing all these First open Android studio followed by emulators.

Answer (score 46):

Sometimes there are conflicts between ADB Genymotion and ADB SDK because both of them use the same port. So I recommend always set up ADB Genymotion to use the ADB SDK, in that way to avoid incompatible issues.

Genymotion-> Settings -> ADB -> Use custom Android SDK tools (here your set up your sdk android location).[image]

Answer (score 11):

The best and working solution is:

1. Close Android Studio
2. Open task manager
3. Kill the process **adb.exe**
4. Open android studio again
5. Problem solved

Answer (score 8):

Close Android studio then go to `Task Manager`

- `End Task` adb.exe
- goto Details menu

  - `End Task` java.exe and jusched.exe

now open Android Studio it will work properly

Answer (score 6):

I solved by End task "adb.exe" background process from task manager.
and Start adb thats it :)

Answer (score 5):

Open the Genymotion emulator after opening The Android studio.

Answer (score 4):

in my case one application on window use adb.exe.

that application name is mobogenie.

Fixed :: 
Goto Window TaskManager select adb.exe and press End process

Answer (score 4):

Just goto the task manager on your PC, and kill adb.exe, then back to your android studio. it should initialize and reconnect.

Comment: While this is an answer, it's a "copy" of a previous answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38920749/4283581). There is no additional value for SO to keep two answers with the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

disconnect any usb connected android devices.  I was tethering to my laptop via my cellphone for internet connection.  I got the adb start server failed error with loopback error "port is only used for one socket connection".

I disconnected my cellphone usb connection from my laptop and now android studio recognizes my genymotion emulator and another android device I have connected via usb in the deployment target box.

Answer (score 0):

if genymotion or emulator not working try to install pdanet+ in your system and mobile device choose your mobile type(motorola,sony,other)it will automatically install driver and run your application in mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

Check the firewall of the system. May be the "allow app to communicate through windows firewall"  may have blocked android studio.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all of the solutions proposed above, but no one of them solve my problem. I had some hour of hadaches trying to solve this problem on my laptop (Ubuntu 20.04). This is how I came to solve it finally.

The problem was that the adb default port 5037 was already taken by another, so the solution became simple :

1. kill the process running on that port (5037) then launch the adb manually
2. launch the adb on another port :

   user~$ adb start-server -P xxxx

   Where xxxx represent another port

Answer (score 0):

There may be a problem with Windows 11. to solve that issue follow the steps

Go to the android studio app
Right-click the app
Go to Properties
Go to compatibility
Check the Run this program in compatibility mode
Select windows version 10 or 8 or 7 Then apply and ok

After these changes start the Android Studio App, This is works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem its the port. The port 5037 its bloqued... In my case, i use visual studio and android studio, and adb run for emulate devices but not run when i need use since terminal.

You only need use :

```bash
adb -P 5000 start-server
adb -P 5000 devices
```

Now you can view the devices...

Its posibble that you need open adb from your adb path, but the process its same

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem after updating the SDK -build tools and platform tools and the emulator tools. I tried restarting my computer, turning off firewalls, killing adb.exe and then trying to run it from the command line, but nothing worked. Fortunately, I had an old version of adb.exe lying around from a previous installation. Following these steps, I was able to fix the problem:

Rename your adb.exe file in C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe to adb_breaks_adb.exe
Copy an older version of adb.exe into the following folder: C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
If you do not have an older version of adb.exe, you can get one by downloading an older version of the Android SDK from on of the links mentioned here:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043522/where-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-the-android-sdk#:~:text=Start%20a%20bounty-,6%20Answers,-Sorted%20by%3A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043522/where-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-the-android-sdk#:%7E:text=Start%20a%20bounty-,6%20Answers,-Sorted%20by%3A)

Restart your Android Studio.