# Where can I download an older version of the Android SDK?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

I want to download an older version of the `Android SDK: 21.0.0,`    Where can I do this?

I currently have the `latest version` of the android SDK, downloaded from [HERE](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=i).

However I want an older version, can the **Full older version** of the SDK be **downloaded** from anywhere?

I am trying to get the older version using `SDK manager`, but It is not working. I.e. it is only giving me build tools etc.

Comment: question is: what for? also your question is off-topic as :Questions asking us to recommend or **find** a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other **off-site resource** are **off-topic for Stack Overflow**

Comment: How is my question off topic?

Comment: @Slevin, to use projects that google breaks with its SDK updates

Answer (score 44):

Have you tried the links at: http://developer.android.com/sdk/older_releases.html?

- OR -

First check [this link](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html) to find out what revision number you need. Then use one of these links:

http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r[rev]-windows.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r[rev]-linux.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r[rev]-macosx.zip

Example for **v21.1** for **Windows**:

http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r21.1-windows.zip

You need to use the exact revision number as listed in the link above. Examples: `22`, `22.0.1`, etc...

Comment: did you check what you can download from there? only some pre 1.6versions

Comment: Thanks, I did but it does not have the SDK I am looking for, it only has from 2007- 2009 releases, I am looking for the release compatible with the Nov 2012 21.0.0 ADT release. Can I find it anywhere?

Comment: Thank you, how would I download SDK Tools r21.0.0? Sorry I do not understand too well!

Comment: I also need the images for these SDKs, do you know where can I download the image for and old SDK and not the new image ? I need armv8 image for older version of the emulator.

Comment: Found this very useful google android repository directory listing program: https://gist.github.com/eagletmt/73a0d33d3d9c2aeb31c30ee05fed528b#file-main-go

Comment: For mac os tools, use 'darwin' instead of 'macosx' like this: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r27.0.0-darwin.zip

Answer (score 7):

Official Android Studio download archives containing **all** releases can be found here: https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

Android Studio will contain the SDK.

Comment: Can you share similar link for sdk tools. I want to downgrade sdk tools.

Comment: Not seeing any SDK in these archives.

Answer (score 3):

https://developer.android.com/sdk/older_releases

This page provides archived and obsolete versions of the Android SDK, including non-current versions of active releases and "early look" versions that were released before Android 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

I was also looking for this & found this little easier to download previous ANDROID SDK version.

> For MAC

- Open Android Studio
- Navigate to Preference as following

> android studio >> preferences >> Appearance & Behaviours >> Android
>   SDK

- On right pane: You can see mapping of SDK against API Levels.
- Select the version you want & Click APPLY.
- This will download the selected SDK version and install.

[image]

Comment: This is not the Android SDK itself. It's part of the Android SDK: Platform

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the SDK Manager, just click "Show Package Details" in the lower right hand corner to display all previous versions of the various tools (SDK Command-line, NDK, Build-Tools). Then select the versions you need.
[Screenshot of Option in Android Studio highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjePI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, but only for Windows: [Android SDK OLD](https://android-sdk.en.uptodown.com/windows/old)