# Flutter doctor shows sdkmanager error for demo app on Mac

Tags: android, flutter

I’m keen to try flutter on my MacBook running MacOS 10.13.3. I’ve been reading with interest this seemingly excellent step-by-step guide:

https://medium.com/@sethladd/installing-flutter-on-a-mac-13a26340f80a

It all goes well until I get to the point where I need to run:

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

but for me I get…

```
Graham-Macbook12-2015:my_first_app graham.hobson$ flutter doctor --android-licenses 
sdkmanager --version failed: 1
```

I have redownloaded Java but that doesn’t fix it. Some articles here suggest that it might be something do with my path and the SDK not being on it, but I can’t see the problem. Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

[Where can I download an older version of the Android SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043522/where-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-the-android-sdk)

View the answer by Maverick09

Hope this helps!

NOTE: I don't have a Mac

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea what version of Android SDK might be best used to fix the issue?

Comment: Try to use one less then what you are using now.