# How to intall older android sdk via android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

Is there any way to install older versions of android SDK via Android Studio? I  don't want to use suspicious download links from the internet and want to be able download it directly from Google. Is it possible?
*P.S. My question is not a duplicate of another one because the other one doesn't consist exact direct instruction about Android studio with the desired button I was searching for.*

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "install older versions of android SDK"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I download an older version of the Android SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043522/where-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-the-android-sdk)

Comment: @CommonsWare use a different version of SDK packages that isn't the newest. Archived releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android Studio, got to File > Settings. Then go to Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK. Open the SDK Platforms tab and, check any SDK versions you want to use.The IDE will download the sources and any other parts of the checked SDK's.