# adb.exe start-server failed--run manually if necessary

Tags: android-studio, sdk, adb, device-driver

I am not able to run the application on my mobile device because of that error "adb.exe start-server failed--run manually if necessary". My laptop recognized my device but i don't know why does android studio did not find any device.
I need this help...

Comment: close studio, Go to taskmanager and kill the `adb` process if running and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue just recently.

I was using Android API v 30 and platform tools 30.0.3.

I just rolled back the platform tools to 30.0.2 and then it worked.

You can download the older versions from here https://androidmtk.com/download-android-sdk-platform-tools

You may have to delete the older .idea folders and .iml files, close the project and close the Idea ide and restart.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem after updating the SDK -build tools and platform tools and the emulator tools.  I tried restarting my computer, turning off firewalls, killing adb.exe and then trying to run it from the command line, but nothing worked.  Fortunately, I had an old version of adb.exe lying around from a previous installation.  Following these steps, I was able to fix the problem:

1. Rename your adb.exe file in C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe to adb_breaks_adb.exe
2. Copy an older version of adb.exe into the following folder: C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\

If you do not have an older version of adb.exe, you can get one by downloading an older version of the Android SDK from on of the links mentioned here:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043522/where-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-the-android-sdk#:~:text=Start%20a%20bounty-,6%20Answers,-Sorted%20by%3A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043522/where-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-the-android-sdk#:%7E:text=Start%20a%20bounty-,6%20Answers,-Sorted%20by%3A)

Restart your Android Studio.