# adb.exe start server failed-run manually if neccessary

Tags: android, adb

When I started running my app in Android, I got a message saying that "adb.exe start server failed-run manually if neccessary".

[image: error1]

I tried many commands shown on Stack Overflow in the command prompt, but the problem is not rectified. This is the error I get,

[image: error2]

I even reinstalled Android Studio, but in vain. And my adb.exe is not found in the Task Manager.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Seems like the privilege issue. You need to start `Android Studio` as administrator or your `adb` with Administrator privilege

Comment: Thank you for replying. I've done this by right click android studio and clicked run as administrator . If this was your suggestion it is not working.Are there any alternatives??

Comment: Are you using gennymotion emulator??

Comment: You can try this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744758/adb-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-on-windows/34727613#34727613

Comment: I'm not using gennymotion emulator.

Comment: When I typed adb devices my output is:-   daemon not running,starting it now on port 5037. error-adb.log:Permission denied.,could not read ok from adb server-*failed to start daemon*

Comment: You must have to add adb path to your PATH environment variable and then you have to try..

Comment: Plz provide us the logs and also check for the port issues.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: @IRadha -What are the possible port issues?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the error?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9nvys.jpg

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rNs4R.jpg

Comment: Is there any solution

Comment: Run your command prompt as administrator and try.

Comment: I've done this many times previously which didn't woked.But now when i put the command adb devices, Output showed daemon started successfully and my device is found..After sometimes it goes into previous state and doing the same command prompt operations it works..Why is it so???Is there any technical explanation?

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me

Answer (score 8):

first close android studio then press <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>delete</kbd>  to open task manager then search for `adb.exe`, click that then press end task. this is the solution that i got from googling,but it didn't work for me.

Then i tried this one, search for `java` in task manager. end task `java(services)` also. then open android studio.it will work

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a genymotion emulator to run the app then to solve this problem first run android studio and then start genymotion.

Comment: Aparna is not using genymotion emulator. Please read the whole page before answering

Answer (score 1):

You can see all the status using cmd. Most of the time adb's home directory ais also available in own PC home director. Such as

> C:\User\USER_NAME

What you have to do is first check the availability of adb. Just type and enter
`adb service` OR `adb` in your cmd

Then you can see adb version, where it's installed and global option and much more info. If those info doesn't appear you should install Android Studio correctly.

Then you can kill the adb server and start the adb serveer

1.to kill--->> `adb kill-server`

2.to start-->> `adb start-server`

All done

Answer (score 0):

just need to exit Android Studio and once again run it as administrator :D

Answer (score -1):

I haven't seen any solution as mine but I think this is similar to the answer above. As for me, this will happen then my Android Studio won't show any devices, at all. I have "search everything" software on my PC and that when I try to search adb.exe I see a lot of app crash folders. It adds a new one everytime I try to run my android program.

So I go to task manager and found multiple adb runs (as much as how many times I tried to run my program). I closed each and every one of them. Then, I will try to run my program again and adb will run and show my devices.

Runs everytime. No restart, reinstall, run, or re-download needed.