# Solution of ADB not responding. You can wait more,or kill "adb.exe" process manually and click 'Restart'

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to follow this link [ddms: 'adb.exe,start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary, Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137634/ddms-adb-exe-start-server-failed-run-manually-if-necessary-android-studio) and it works for me.

you can also try this process

```
adb kill-server
```

then

```
adb start-server
```

then

```
adb nodaemon server
```

output `cannot bind 'tcp:5037'`

then @Parth Anjaria comment from [how to restart ADB manually from Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826101/how-to-restart-adb-manually-from-android-studio) this link.

This problem's solution varies.

Comment: You cannot @ someone inside a question... What exactly **is** the question?

Comment: got it @cricket_007.

Comment: "and it works"... Okay, then again, what is the problem?

Comment: problem was i couldn't connect my ADB with android studio and it pop up
**ADB not responding. If you'd like to retry, then please manually kill “adb.exe” and click 'Restart'**

Comment: And according to the post here, you have solved it? That isn't the format of the Q&A site as StackOverflow. You are welcome to post above "this is my error, how do I solve it", and *below* you can post "here's what I did, and it worked".