# My adb is showing error again and again

Tags: android, adb

I've tried all possibilities like adb-kill server and start-server in cmd and it's getting done for that time but after shutting down pc and starting android studio it's showing the same error again and again.

Is there any permanent solution for my problem?

My error is :

```
'C:\Users\Srinu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
```

Comment: And what is that error?

Comment: Post the error you which you are geting

Comment: @ErenTantekin I've added error msg

Comment: @AkhileshPatil I've added error msg

Comment: did you tried to run as an administrator of Android studio

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/38920749/1548824

Comment: @AkhileshPatil Sir, Is there any connection between running as administrator and this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ddms: 'adb.exe,start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary, Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137634/ddms-adb-exe-start-server-failed-run-manually-if-necessary-android-studio)