# Flutter Unable to run "adb", check your Android SDK installation and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable

Tags: android, flutter, sdk, adb, root

everytime i run flutter doctor i am facing this issue how can i get rid out of it plz hep.
[flutter error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ko2sF.png)

Comment: Please reinstall the Flitter and Android SDK and try agin!

Comment: This worked for me, and is very easy to do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38920749/9915119

Answer (score 5):

Kindly first of all check your latest sdk first step:
[image]

Second step:
[image]

Third step:
Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` Press Y against each agreement

If you have done above steps then please follow the bellow process

Flutter provides a command to update the Android SDK path:

Use `flutter config --android-sdk <path-to-your-android-sdk-path>`

Normally the Android SDK path is `C:\Users[your Local user folder]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`

Comment: Hope this helps you...if not please inform in comments

Comment: plus, you might need to disable proxy in AVD settings
https://pasteboard.co/GN5HGJSmAlzr.png

Answer (score 5):

Go to activity monitor (mac) or Task Manager (Window). 
End all **adb** tasks and re-run.

Answer (score 2):

For Me.
The problem is the antivirus program. It denied access to starting the flutter daemon on port 5037. I disabled/exited the antivirus program. Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

This generally occurs if the platform-tools are not installed properly. Reinstalling the platform tools might fix this problem. Open Android Studio, click SDK Manager in the toolbar or click Tools > SDK Manager, click SDK Tools, then uncheck Android-SDK Platform-Tools (as shown above). After this, open C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk and delete the platform-tools folder. Then go back to Android Studio and in the SDK Tools, check-mark ‘✓’ Android-SDK Platform-Tools.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue and I run flutter doctor --android-licenses, retried the flutter doctor, and error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

You have to just do this on windows

> the adb daemon was unable to start (when trying adb devices). Doing
> the following via an Admin CMD worked: `net stop winnat`, then

```
net start winnat.
```

Then try again.